# IPv6 hotspot on RPi with NetworkManager

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-networking, ipv6

I try to create WiFi hotspot on Raspberry OS (Bookworm) with NetworkManager.

The basic tutorial
https://raspberrytips.com/access-point-setup-raspberry-pi/
helped - I've got IPv4 hotspot which shares IPv4 from Ethernet connection (eth0).

However I have IPv6 /64 only Wireguard interface wg0 on this RPi. It is originated from Hurricane Electric broker (/48 network) and landed via VPS and Wireguard on RPi.

Is there way to add IPv6 support to WiFi hotspot ? What is the correct way here ?
I'd be happy with both dual stack or IPv6-only hotspot.

Few years ago I've implemented this via hostapd / radvd but maybe NetworkManager simplifies this too ?

Thanks a lot !